# Signing kernel mode driver for Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, code-signing, kernel-module, code-signing-certificate

Until recently I had working an EV-certificate from GlobalSign that allowed me to sign a Windows kernel mode driver and load that driver under Windows 8.1.  Unfortunately, this certificate expired and I had to renew it.  I learned that drivers signed with my new certificate no longer load under Windows 8.1 since the the necessary cross certificates [expired](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/deprecation-of-software-publisher-certificates-and-commercial-release-certificates) and were not renewed by Microsoft.  Instead, [I am told](https://support.globalsign.com/code-signing/expiration-of-kmcs-certificates) by GlobalSign that Microsoft will now sign my driver for use under Windows 8.1, but I can not get that to work.

If I understand correctly, I must use the [Hardware Dev Center](https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/hardware/Search) to submit my driver to Microsoft, but when I do the only options are to request attestation signing for a variety of Windows 10/11 versions, but not for Windows 8/8.1.  Drivers signed for Windows 10 do not load under Windows 8.1.[image: 4]

Is there really no way to get my driver (a network filter driver without any hardware attached) signed or am I misunderstanding something?  [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/hardware-submission-create) article talks about WLK and WCK test results that I can get signed.  I assume that this is not what I want, since for Windows 10/11 I don't need to run them as well.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that we can't request to sign driver for Windows 8.1 on the Hardware Dev Center.

FYI, I succeeded to install my USB kernel mode driver which is signed on May 2022 with EV Code Signing Certificates from GlobalSign on Windows 7. I saw no error or caution.
So...I don't know why but it seems that we can use cross certificates expired from Microsoft. I think the result is same on Windows 8.1.

Comment: I had the same experience that the chain of certificates contained cross certs that were at the time of signing already expired, yet the driver would load nevertheless and signtool didn't complain.